# Slack isn't connected

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often encounter this warning popup. How can I get rid of it?

[image: warning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Code Time extension might be trying to connect to Slack. If you don't use slack, then just skip this step in the code time extension settings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the Code Time extension. This popup has been appearing frequently but not after I've disabled Slack in the Code Time Settings, that seems to fix the issue for me.

[Disable slack workspace in Code Time extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFJfJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

When slack desktop application can't connect, it is possible that your network configuration or any other security device (proxy, firewall, antivirus or VPN) is interfiering.

### Steps to solve it

> (**check
> https://slack.com/intl/en-gb/help/articles/205138367-Troubleshoot-connection-issues**)

*Step 1:* Clean the cache and relaunch Slack.

Click on **Relaunch Slack**, under error message.

*Step 2:* Get your **.Net logs** and send them to Slack Help Center
(https://slack.com/intl/en-gb/help/requests/new?geocode=en-gb&aid=205138367&from_hc=1&src=article)

If the problem isn't solved, get the networks log in the Slack desktop app and send them so they can check your issue individually. To get the network logs, click on the button "Download logs" under error message.

Comment: What if i don't want to use it at all?

Comment: thank you but it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Uhmm I just put what the slack official webpage had as answers... I think you should write to them to see if they can solve your problem